# How can I add a margin with color in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a margin with color in bootstrap 4.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. You need to show a sample of your markup, and it's not clear where you want the color.

Comment: @Nick, answers go down there (but you shouldn't answer unclear questions anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Margins don´t have color, these img look like child inside some html tag and the parent have the background color.

Just put a body `background-color` style, place a div with other color.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i could understand but maybe that's what you want to achieve:

pick the div you want the margin with color and add this css code:

example

```
<div class="container" style="border:100px solid #c51a1a;">  
</div>
```